# Getting value of p tag with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using jquery to try to take the value text in a p tag.

I set up an alert for testing to give me the value and it says "current stack is [object Object]"

My html for this is

```
<div id="player9">
    <div class="player_stats">
      <p class="player_name"></p>
      <p class="player_action"></p>
      <p class="player_money"></p>
   </div>
</div>
```

My alert code is:

```
alert("current stack is " + $("#player9").children(".player_stats").children("p.player_money"));
```

if I add .val() it comes back as undefined.
These values were set upon page load by:

```
$(whichseat[seat]).children(".hand").children("p.bet").text(bet);
```

"whichseat[seat] and bet are based into the function.  They are setting correctly.

If I use firebug and checkout that specific p tag it says:

```
<p class="player_money">60000</p>
```

How do I correctly grab that value?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) or [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

```
alert("current stack is " + $("#player9").children(".player_stats").children("p.player_money").html());
```

Or:

```
alert("current stack is " + $("#player9").children(".player_stats").children("p.player_money").text());
```

Obviously the text method will grab just the text, where as the html will get the markup as well. [**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Scoobler/ua9zN/)

Comment: If i do .html() it returns null  if I do .text its nothing.   I know there is text there.  I see it on the page and I see it when I inspect that element with firebug

Comment: Take a look at the updated demo - it shows it working. Do you have more than one set of elements which could match your search, so you are seeing null from the first lot it finds?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `text()` method. The val() method is used for getting input field's values. So, you will have:

```
alert("current stack is " + $("#player9").children(".player_stats").children("p.player_money").text());
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what else I'm missing, but since you're setting the inner text with [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text), you get it using the same method.

If all else fails you may have to specify to get the inner text of exactly one element:

```
$("#player9 > .player_stats > p.player_money:first").text()
```